# SSD Partition on Windows 10

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

I have a new Laptop with a 512 GB SSD with pre-installed Windows 10. I'm planning to create two partitions: **C** for program files + OS and **D** for personal data + Windows linux subshell.

Does Windows built in Disk Management work well for partitioning? Does it give proper 4K alignment or will that require third party software?

Does the following partitioning make sense?
C - 200GB
D - remaining GB

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning with disk management has always served me well, and typically will cause no problems.

If you are worried about 4K alignment, you can check that using built in Windows tools.

In "Run" (Windows key + R) type msinfo32 and hit **Enter**. Then go to "**Components >Storage > Disks** and look for your SSD and check the Partition Starting Offsets. It needs to be divisible by 4096; otherwise the SSD block is not alignment correct."[1](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/ssd-alignment-windows-10-3889.html)

Here is what it looks like in my case, luckily, all are divisible by 4096. 
[image]

[1](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/ssd-alignment-windows-10-3889.html) Source for 4K checking: https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/ssd-alignment-windows-10-3889.html

Answer (score 0):

I did it 1 year ago on my office laptop, live, on the installed Windows 10 64-bit. It came with 1TB disk but one single partition on it occupying the whole disk.
First I selected the "C" drive and selected "Shrink Volume": it didn't let me reduce it to less than 512G. I let it shrink to that value, then rebooted and second time it let me shrink it even more to less than 200G. On the rest of disk I created new volume called "D" and formatted it as NTFS: there I keep the data, virtual boxes installations, etc.

[My 1TB disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHn2w.png)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, windows disk management will perfectly do your job, no need for any third party softwares. 
and if you want to install your programs in C drive then 200 gb is fine else you can decrease the size as windows installation takes not more than 20~25gb